# json API data with all of its content

Tags: steam

I need to show json api data on website. But i am unable to do so am using following script. This just returns data in json format. I want to shownews in proper format along with images.

```html
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=570&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},

]',"}

]",$json);
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have asked, I hope you will find this helpful:

**CSS** *paste it in between `<head><style>here</style></head>`*

```css
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
.news-entry {
    color: #606060;
    font: 11px/18px Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    padding: 1px 0;
    width: 630px;
}
.news-title {
    color: #848484;
    font: 10px Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    width: 630px;
}
.news-title h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #1c4670;
    color: #2771a5;
    font: 24px/30px "Trebuchet MS",Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
.news-title-info {
    height: 22px;
    width: 630px;
}
.news-date {
    float: left;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
.news-author {
    float: right !important;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding-left: 16px;
 color:#00C;
}
.featured-news {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 630px;
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
```

**Code** *paste it in between `<body>here</body>`*

```html
<?php 
$json_url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=570&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json";
$json  = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json  = str_replace('},]',"}]",$json);
$data  = json_decode($json, true);
$appnews = $data['appnews']['newsitems'];
?>
<div id="header">
 <h1>News</h1>
</div>
<div class="featured-news">
<?php
    foreach($appnews as $news)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="news-entry">
        <h2><a href=""><?php echo $news['title']; ?></a></h2>
        <div class="news-title-info">
            <div class="news-date"><?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', $news['date']); ?></div>
            <?php
   if(!empty($news['author'])){
   ?> 
                <div class="news-author">By <?php echo $news['author']; ?></a></div>
         <?php
   }
   ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-entry">
        <p>
            <img width="72" height="90" align="left" alt="Dota 2" src="http://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/DavzDRpQ36gGQGmiwELPs5-650-80.jpg" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">
            <?php echo $news['contents']; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a class="" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $news['url']; ?>">Read more</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
Some footer here...
</div>
```

PS: You have to change to path of the image for the image you like as there is no field for news image in the json returned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code is working fine. But I wanted to display images related to news. Its showing same image on every news.In RSS feed you can have images related to news, whereas with API unable to get any images.

Comment: There isn't any field in the returned JSON data for image url, so, I have just put some random image path.